# How to pass two random numbers by their html id to a function in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I am trying to implement a math captcha with javascript. I have created the random numbers with

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
  $('#num1').text(Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1);
  $('#num2').text(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1);
}); 
</script>
```

Then put them somewhere in the form like this:

```
<div>
<span id="num1"></span> +
<span id="num2"></span> =
<input id="captcha" type="text" />
</div>
```

and then verify:

```
$.validator.addMethod('captcha',
function(value) {
$result = ( parseInt($('#num1').val()) + parseInt($('#num2').val()) == parseInt($('#captcha').val()) ) ;
return $result;
},
'Numbers do not match, please try again.'
);
```

BUT there are two problems: one is that the random numbers are generated sometimes and sometimes not. The seond problem is the verification. I want to sum the two generated numbers and see if the summed number equals the input number, then return true, but somehow the document.getElementById('num1').value doesn't pass the generated numbers.  Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE:

```
var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
$('#num1').text(number1);
$('#num2').text(number2);

$.validator.addMethod('captcha',
function(value) {
$result = $('#num1').text(number1).val() + $('#num2').text(number2).val() == parseInt($('#captcha').val()) ;
return $result;
},
'Numbers do not match, please try again.'
);
```

Comment: Why do you have a `setInterval` there?

Comment: span's do not have values. Use `$('#num1').text()` to get the number instead.

Comment: Captcha verification on the client side ?

Comment: I fixed those based on your comments, but now the validation doesn't work, that is even if the answer is correct, it still gives me the error message.

Comment: Why put `$('#num1').text(number1).val()` when you can just put `number1`? Also, you should wrap your code in a `$(document).ready();`

Comment: try this one `$result = number1 + number2 === parseInt($('#captcha').val());`

Comment: It is wrapped in $(document).ready(); Yep, number1 + number2 == parseInt($('#captcha').val()); did the trick. Thank you guys/girls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the issue in the comments, but in case someone else reads this post.

If you have already stored the numbers to variables, just add the variables together and don't worry about the span's values

> ```
> var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
> var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
> $('#num1').text(number1);
> $('#num2').text(number2);
>
> $.validator.addMethod('captcha',
> function(value) {
>     $result = number1 + number2 == parseInt($('#captcha').val()) ;
>     return $result;
> }, 'Numbers do not match, please try again.');
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking how to tick the question anwered :)

Answer (score 3):

value property doesn't return text for element like span, use innerHTML `document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML` or, if you use jQuery `$('#num1').text()`. But this kind of captcha can be broken easily because data about the answer is on client side, you should use backend to verify the input data.